# Access folder like P2P without Static IP

Tags: p2p

We are using a billing software like tally at a remote location with multiple user option. Our ISP is not able to provide a Static IP address there and We need to access a folder by P2P connectivity.

Can a multi-user licence be used at a different location. 
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN connection. Have the remote site connect to the central network, perhaps using a site-to-site VPN on the router, or at least some "regular" VPN software on the specific computer.

(Common freeware choices are OpenVPN, IPsec, ocserv, ZeroTier, ... Many routers and OSes are capable of using IPsec natively; Linux has strongSwan and LibreSwan for that.)